# Jquery events for dynamically loaded plugin

Tags: jquery, function, jquery-ui, event-handling

I am using a jquery plugin to create a input number spinner. It does not work on dynamically loaded html elements as expected. The current code is

```
$('.qty').spinedit({
    minimum: 1,
    maximum: 10000,
    step: 1,
});
```

I guess I need to register this to newly added content using something like

```
$('#static-element').on('the event', '.qty', function(){
   // do something here
});
```

But what is the event that I need to use considering no user input is required, no click, no change etc.
It's as if I need to use some kind of `ready` event or `load`.
What is the correct way of adding functionality to dynamically injected content without user input.

Comment: What do you mean dynamically injected content? Is the whole spinner thing automated? Like does it happen without any user interaction or input? Or is it like the user inputs a number then it spins?

Comment: check my answer

Comment: This is spinedit - [link](https://github.com/geersch/bootstrap-spinedit)

Comment: Please create a [Minimal,Complete, Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example, so that we can check it.

Comment: The input fields (x10) are converted to `spinedit` elements at document load allowing the website user to use the arrows to increase or decrease the numeric value of each individual text input field, it works exactly as the `spinedit` plugin is designed to work. However, when a new text input field is dynamically added to the page, making 11 in total, with the exact same classes as the first 10 then it is not converted into a `spinedit` input, it is simply rendered as a generic html text input. `Spinedit` is not being applied to dynamically added text inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You must register dynamic text elements after you append it to document body. Example:

```
var $textElem = $("<input>").attr("type","text").appendTo("body");
$($textElem).spinedit({
  minimum: 1,
  maximum: 10000,
  step: 1,
});
```